# Categories Going to different Blog Pages?

Tags: categories

I've searched for this but can't find a clear answer.

I'd like to have my main blog page display posts with certain categories and then have another blog page that shows different categories.

How would I do this?

Thank yoU!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a template page, and in that page, you'd have the logic to display the categories you want to show. Your template page would look something like this:

```
/*
Template Name: Secondary Blog Page
*/

get_header();

/*Code for your custom category display*/
$customcats = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 12,13,15  //Category ID's
));
if($customcats->have_posts()):

while($customcats->have_posts()): $customcats->the_post();
    //code to display the posts however you want
endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Then you'd create a new page, and choose this template to render it.